# How can I load a CSV empty strings as a NULL in SQL Server while using FileHelpers?

Tags: c#, ado.net, filehelpers

I am using FileHelpers to read a CSV with the intent of loading a SQL Server table.

The CSV looks something like this:

```
ID, SOMESTRING
"10","Blah blah"
"11",""
"12","More blah blah"
```

My Record Mapping class looks something like this:

```
[IgnoreFirst, DelimitedRecord(",")]
class Mytable
{
    [FieldQuoted]
    public ulong Id;

    [FieldQuoted]
    [FieldNullValue(typeof(string), null)]
    public string SomeString;
}
```

Finally, the code to bulk copy to the DB is:

```
  SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(mySqlConnection);
  bc.DestinationTableName = "dbo.MYTABLE";
  bc.WriteToServer(new FileHelperEngine<Mytable>().ReadFile(baseDir + "\\" + "MYTABLE.CSV").ToDataTable<Mytable>());
```

Initially, I did not include the FieldNullValue attribute, but including it or not does not appear to matter. In both cases, row 11 imports as an empty string in SQL Server. I would like it to be NULL. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With FileHelpers an empty string will be parsed as `String.Empty`, but you can override this with a custom converter:

```
public class EmptyStringConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object StringToField(string sourceString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceString))
            return null;
        return sourceString;
    }
}
```

Then you define your record class property like this

```
[FieldConverter(typeof(EmptyStringConverter))]
public string SomeString;
```

If the string corresponding to `SomeString` is empty or blank, it will be converted to null.

Comment: I was rather hoping for a default parameter in the config file to change the default behaviour, but this did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you meant using CsvHelper. Yes, it can be done. I was able to test your scenario and was able to verify attribute SOMESTRING = NULL while using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014.
In my example, using CsvHelper to convert a CSV file into a DataTable, then converting any field that is empty into DBNull.Value.
Inserting the Modified DataTable into Database using Database Stored Procedure and using User-Defined Table Types
Finally, reading from the Database -> DataTable and view the records in DataGridView.
Your will notice empty fields are NULL.

### Create a TYPE

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyProductTableType] AS TABLE(
    [ID] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [SOMETHING] [nvarchar](128) NULL
)
```

### Create a Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTable]
    @myTableType MyProductTableType readonly
AS
BEGIN
    insert into [dbo].PRODUCTS select * from @myTableType 
END
```

### C# Code when using a DataGridView and a Command Button on the Windows.Forms

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using CsvHelper;

using System.IO;

namespace Stack_Test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var path = @"C:\Temp\MYTABLE.csv";
        DataTable dt = readCSV(path);

        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {                
            foreach(DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                if (row.Field<String>(col) == String.Empty)
                {
                    row.SetField(col, DBNull.Value); //row.SetField(col, "NULL"); // Or set the value to any string value of your choice
                }
            }
        }            
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your SQL Connection String");            
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("InsertTable", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@myTableType", dt));
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Dispose();
            dt.Clear();                                                    
        }

        using(var command = new SqlCommand("Select * from PRODUCTS", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.Text})
        {                
            SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();              
            dt.Load(rdr);
            dataGridView1.DataBindings.Clear();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.Refresh();                
            dt.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }            
    } // End button1_Click
```

### using CsvHelper

```
public DataTable readCSV(string filePath)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(filePath));
    // Creating the columns
    typeof(Product).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList().ForEach(x => dt.Columns.Add(x));

    // Adding the rows
    csv.GetRecords<Product>().ToList().ForEach(line => dt.Rows.Add(line.ID, line.SOMETHING));
    return dt;
} // End readCSV : DataTable
```

### A class object

```
public class Product
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string SOMETHING { get; set; }
} // End class Product
```

[SQL Server - DB Result Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCIZu.png)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, but as I mentioned in the description I am using FileHelpers. I didn't come across CvsHelper and might have used it if I had, but having already done it with FileHelpers I'd rather stick with that for now. I have modified the question title to be more explicit. Again, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the FileHelper package you are using but the problem is that the value for row 11 is `""` not `null`.

Maybe you could expand the `SomeString` property definition, like this

```
private string _SomeString;

[FieldQuoted]
[FieldNullValue(typeof(string), null)]
public string SomeString { get {return _SomeString;} 
                           set {if (value == null || value.length == 0)    
                                    _SomeString = null;
                                else
                                    _SomeString = value;} }
```

Comment: This felt like it should have been on the right track, but I found that using this Property and member variable approach to be problematic. FileHelpers appears to be using reflection and didn't differentiate between the property and the member so ran through them both which caused issues. Though I don't think I tried it exactly as you've suggested, but I gave up when I first observed the problem. Thanks!